# How resize image in Joomla?

Tags: image, joomla, resize

I try use this:

```
$image = new JImage();
$image->loadFile($item->logo);
$image->resize('208', '125');

$properties = JImage::getImageFileProperties($item->logo);

echo $image->toFile(JPATH_CACHE . DS . $item->logo, $properties->type);
```

But not work =\ any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this out:

```
// Set the path to the file
$file = '/Absolute/Path/To/File';

// Instantiate our JImage object
$image = new JImage($file);

// Get the file's properties
$properties = JImage::getImageFileProperties($file);

// Declare the size of our new image
$width = 100;
$height = 100;

// Resize the file as a new object
$resizedImage = $image->resize($width, $height, true);

// Determine the MIME of the original file to get the proper type for output
$mime = $properties->mime;

if ($mime == 'image/jpeg')
{
    $type = IMAGETYPE_JPEG;
}
elseif ($mime == 'image/png')
{
    $type = IMAGETYPE_PNG;
}
elseif ($mime == 'image/gif')
{
    $type = IMAGETYPE_GIF;
}

// Store the resized image to a new file
$resizedImage->toFile('/Absolute/Path/To/New/File', $type);
```

Comment: `getImageFileProperties()` is a static method, so the call should be `$properties = JImage::getImageFileProperties($file)` instead. Otherwise, thanks for the great answer!

Comment: @Michael - Many thanks for Your answer I will edit it to remove some bugs and ad some extra stuff

Comment: @Michael This save my day, but I suggest to use createThumbs instead of resize (if you need exact size images as me of cause).

Comment: There is a small error in line 4: 
new JImage($originalFile);  should be: JImage($file);

This is nitpicking, but I would also suggest to use Variables for the width and height, the Strings in your example initially confused me.
I.e.: Declare: $width=100;$height=100; And then use $image->resize($width,$height, true);